# mongodb 4.2 sort by id slow with compound index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have docs in the fasion

```
{
  _id: ...,
  p: [
       {
         k: 'stringvalue',
         v: 'stringvalue'
       },
       ...
     ]
}
```

`_id` is provided to drivers as a sequence number of insertion, e.g. `...0001`, `....0002`, etc.

That works extermely well for find queries, now I have added sort condition and added `_id` field to the compound index (see below).
That works extermely bad around x100 slower, what could be the reason? The server has plenty of RAM.

```
db.getCollection('mycoll').find({ p: { '$elemMatch': { k: 'd', v: { '$gt': '2019-10-16T08:01:39.741' } } } }).sort({_id: 1}).explain()
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "mydb.mycoll",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "p" : {
                                "$elemMatch" : {
                                        "$and" : [
                                                {
                                                        "k" : {
                                                                "$eq" : "d"
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "v" : {
                                                                "$gt" : "2019-10-16T08:01:39.741"
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                "queryHash" : "E28632C1",
                "planCacheKey" : "E28632C1",
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "SORT",
                        "sortPattern" : {
                                "_id" : 1
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                                        "filter" : {
                                                "p" : {
                                                        "$elemMatch" : {
                                                                "$and" : [
                                                                        {
                                                                                "k" : {
                                                                                        "$eq" : "d"
                                                                                }
                                                                        },
                                                                        {
                                                                                "v" : {
                                                                                        "$gt" : "2019-10-16T08:01:39.741"
                                                                                }
                                                                        }
                                                                ]
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        },
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                        "p.k" : 1,
                                                        "p.v" : 1,
                                                        "_id" : 1
                                                },
                                                "indexName" : "p.k_1_p.v_1__id_1",
                                                "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                        "p.k" : [
                                                                "p"
                                                        ],
                                                        "p.v" : [
                                                                "p"
                                                        ],
                                                        "_id" : [ ]
                                                },
                                                "isUnique" : false,
                                                "isSparse" : false,
                                                "isPartial" : false,
                                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                "direction" : "forward",
                                                "indexBounds" : {
                                                        "p.k" : [
                                                                "[\"d\", \"d\"]"
                                                        ],
                                                        "p.v" : [
                                                                "(\"2019-10-16T08:01:39.741\", {})"
                                                        ],
                                                        "_id" : [
                                                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                        ]
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [
                        {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "filter" : {
                                        "p" : {
                                                "$elemMatch" : {
                                                        "$and" : [
                                                                {
                                                                        "k" : {
                                                                                "$eq" : "d"
                                                                        }
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                        "v" : {
                                                                                "$gt" : "2019-10-16T08:01:39.741"
                                                                        }
                                                                }
                                                        ]
                                                }
                                        }
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "_id" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "_id_",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                "_id" : [ ]
                                        },
                                        "isUnique" : true,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "_id" : [
                                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "dev-10-178-3-247",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "4.2.0",
                "gitVersion" : "a4b751dcf51dd249c5865812b390cfd1c0129c30"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

```
> db.getCollection('mycoll').getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "mydb.mycoll"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "p.k" : 1,
                        "p.v" : 1,
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "p.k_1_p.v_1__id_1",
                "ns" : "mydb.mycoll"
        }
]
```

```
{
"executionStats" : {
  "executionSuccess" : true,
  "nReturned" : 1015268,
  "executionTimeMillis" : 77032,
  "totalKeysExamined" : 3122749,
  "totalDocsExamined" : 3122749,
  "executionStages" : {
          "stage" : "FETCH",
          "filter" : {
                  "p" : {
                          "$elemMatch" : {
                                  "$and" : [
                                          {
                                                  "k" : {
                                                          "$eq" : "d"
                                                  }
                                          },
                                          {
                                                  "v" : {
                                                          "$gt" : "2019-10-16T08:01:39.741"
                                                  }
                                          }
                                  ]
                          }
                  }
          },
          "nReturned" : 1015268,
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 16092,
          "works" : 3122750,
          "advanced" : 1015268,
          "needTime" : 2107481,
          "needYield" : 0,
          "saveState" : 24469,
          "restoreState" : 24469,
          "isEOF" : 1,
          "docsExamined" : 3122749,
          "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
          "inputStage" : {
                  "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                  "nReturned" : 3122749,
                  "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 492,
                  "works" : 3122750,
                  "advanced" : 3122749,
                  "needTime" : 0,
                  "needYield" : 0,
                  "saveState" : 24469,
                  "restoreState" : 24469,
                  "isEOF" : 1,
                  "keyPattern" : {
                          "_id" : 1
                  },
                  "indexName" : "_id_",
                  "isMultiKey" : false,
                  "multiKeyPaths" : {
                          "_id" : [ ]
                  },
                  "isUnique" : true,
                  "isSparse" : false,
                  "isPartial" : false,
                  "indexVersion" : 2,
                  "direction" : "forward",
                  "indexBounds" : {
                          "_id" : [
                                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                          ]
                  },
                  "keysExamined" : 3122749,
                  "seeks" : 1,
                  "dupsTested" : 0,
                  "dupsDropped" : 0
          }
  },
  "allPlansExecution" : [
          {
                  "nReturned" : 0,
                  "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 85,
                  "totalKeysExamined" : 9298,
                  "totalDocsExamined" : 9298,
                  "executionStages" : {
                          "stage" : "SORT",
                          "nReturned" : 0,
                          "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 85,
                          "works" : 9300,
                          "advanced" : 0,
                          "needTime" : 9299,
                          "needYield" : 0,
                          "saveState" : 7391,
                          "restoreState" : 7391,
                          "isEOF" : 0,
                          "sortPattern" : {
                                  "_id" : 1
                          },
                          "memUsage" : 33559558,
                          "memLimit" : 33554432,
                          "inputStage" : {
                                  "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                                  "nReturned" : 9298,
                                  "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 71,
                                  "works" : 9299,
                                  "advanced" : 9298,
                                  "needTime" : 1,
                                  "needYield" : 0,
                                  "saveState" : 7391,
                                  "restoreState" : 7391,
                                  "isEOF" : 0,
                                  "inputStage" : {
                                          "stage" : "FETCH",
                                          "filter" : {
                                                  "p" : {
                                                          "$elemMatch" : {
                                                                  "$and" : [
                                                                          {
                                                                                  "k" : {
                                                                                          "$eq" : "d"
                                                                                  }
                                                                          },
                                                                          {
                                                                                  "v" : {
                                                                                          "$gt" : "2019-10-16T08:01:39.741"
                                                                                  }
                                                                          }
                                                                  ]
                                                          }
                                                  }
                                          },
                                          "nReturned" : 9298,
                                          "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 58,
                                          "works" : 9298,
                                          "advanced" : 9298,
                                          "needTime" : 0,
                                          "needYield" : 0,
                                          "saveState" : 7391,
                                          "restoreState" : 7391,
                                          "isEOF" : 0,
                                          "docsExamined" : 9298,
                                          "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                                          "inputStage" : {
                                                  "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                  "nReturned" : 9298,
                                                  "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                                  "works" : 9298,
                                                  "advanced" : 9298,
                                                  "needTime" : 0,
                                                  "needYield" : 0,
                                                  "saveState" : 7391,
                                                  "restoreState" : 7391,
                                                  "isEOF" : 0,
                                                  "keyPattern" : {
                                                          "p.k" : 1,
                                                          "p.v" : 1,
                                                          "_id" : 1
                                                  },
                                                  "indexName" : "p.k_1_p.v_1__id_1",
                                                  "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                  "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                          "p.k" : [
                                                                  "p"
                                                          ],
                                                          "p.v" : [
                                                                  "p"
                                                          ],
                                                          "_id" : [ ]
                                                  },
                                                  "isUnique" : false,
                                                  "isSparse" : false,
                                                  "isPartial" : false,
                                                  "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                  "direction" : "forward",
                                                  "indexBounds" : {
                                                          "p.k" : [
                                                                  "[\"d\", \"d\"]"
                                                          ],
                                                          "p.v" : [
                                                                  "(\"2019-10-16T08:01:39.741\", {})"
                                                          ],
                                                          "_id" : [
                                                                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                          ]
                                                  },
                                                  "keysExamined" : 9298,
                                                  "seeks" : 1,
                                                  "dupsTested" : 9298,
                                                  "dupsDropped" : 0
                                          }
                                  }
                          }
                  }
          },
          {
                  "nReturned" : 0,
                  "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 85,
                  "totalKeysExamined" : 9298,
                  "totalDocsExamined" : 9298,
                  "executionStages" : {
                          "stage" : "SORT",
                          "nReturned" : 0,
                          "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 85,
                          "works" : 9301,
                          "advanced" : 0,
                          "needTime" : 9299,
                          "needYield" : 0,
                          "saveState" : 24469,
                          "restoreState" : 24469,
                          "isEOF" : 0,
                          "sortPattern" : {
                                  "_id" : 1
                          },
                          "memUsage" : 33559558,
                          "memLimit" : 33554432,
                          "inputStage" : {
                                  "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                                  "nReturned" : 9298,
                                  "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 71,
                                  "works" : 9299,
                                  "advanced" : 9298,
                                  "needTime" : 1,
                                  "needYield" : 0,
                                  "saveState" : 24469,
                                  "restoreState" : 24469,
                                  "isEOF" : 0,
                                  "inputStage" : {
                                          "stage" : "FETCH",
                                          "filter" : {
                                                  "p" : {
                                                          "$elemMatch" : {
                                                                  "$and" : [
                                                                          {
                                                                                  "k" : {
                                                                                          "$eq" : "d"
                                                                                  }
                                                                          },
                                                                          {
                                                                                  "v" : {
                                                                                          "$gt" : "2019-10-16T08:01:39.741"
                                                                                  }
                                                                          }
                                                                  ]
                                                          }
                                                  }
                                          },
                                          "nReturned" : 9298,
                                          "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 58,
                                          "works" : 9298,
                                          "advanced" : 9298,
                                          "needTime" : 0,
                                          "needYield" : 0,
                                          "saveState" : 24469,
                                          "restoreState" : 24469,
                                          "isEOF" : 0,
                                          "docsExamined" : 9298,
                                          "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                                          "inputStage" : {
                                                  "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                  "nReturned" : 9298,
                                                  "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                                  "works" : 9298,
                                                  "advanced" : 9298,
                                                  "needTime" : 0,
                                                  "needYield" : 0,
                                                  "saveState" : 24469,
                                                  "restoreState" : 24469,
                                                  "isEOF" : 0,
                                                  "keyPattern" : {
                                                          "p.k" : 1,
                                                          "p.v" : 1,
                                                          "_id" : 1
                                                  },
                                                  "indexName" : "p.k_1_p.v_1__id_1",
                                                  "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                  "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                          "p.k" : [
                                                                  "p"
                                                          ],
                                                          "p.v" : [
                                                                  "p"
                                                          ],
                                                          "_id" : [ ]
                                                  },
                                                  "isUnique" : false,
                                                  "isSparse" : false,
                                                  "isPartial" : false,
                                                  "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                  "direction" : "forward",
                                                  "indexBounds" : {
                                                          "p.k" : [
                                                                  "[\"d\", \"d\"]"
                                                          ],
                                                          "p.v" : [
                                                                  "(\"2019-10-16T08:01:39.741\", {})"
                                                          ],
                                                          "_id" : [
                                                                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                          ]
                                                  },
                                                  "keysExamined" : 9298,
                                                  "seeks" : 1,
                                                  "dupsTested" : 9298,
                                                  "dupsDropped" : 0
                                          }
                                  }
                          }
                  }
          }
  ]
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Can you update the post with the index definitions; `db.mycoll.getIndexes()` . Sure, the sort is _not_ using the index.

Comment: @prasad_ Updated.

Comment: can you play explain("executionStats")? Are your p arrays big (you will have an index entry for each array element)

Comment: I see that the _rejected plans_ shows that the query is running without the in-memory sort. That is something _you want_ in a query's sort (that means the sort is using the index that is already in the memory _and_ you dont want an in-memory sort, "stage" : "SORT"). It is difficult to tell what **exactly** is wrong with your query and indexes without more information (for example, amount of data). I suggest do couple of things: _[continued in the following comment...]_

Comment: **...** (1) Run explain with "allPlansExecution" mode, and (2) Change your index usage so that the compound index doesn't use the _id as its third key (for trial purpose only). Run the query plans and study the results (before and after the change). With the execution stats for all plans (winning and rejected) you can easily diagnose the issue (and eventually  solve the problem).